# Separate Declaration and Definition of private Node implementation in template Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, template

I was practicing implementing a template Linked List with a private node implementation.  I know one of the methods to define template class member functions is to keep the declaration and definition in the same header file.  When I tried to do this with the private createNode() function, I could not get it to work.

```
template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::createNode(const T &data)
{ ... }
```

I was wondering if there's a way to define the private function createNode() outside of the class declaration?  My current work around is to define this function within the class definition.  As I understand, this is a C++ style no-no though.

Generally speaking, I was wondering if there was anything else I could do with my implementation that could improve readability or make the  code more robust.  I'm open to any and all suggestions!  I suppose the first suggestion is to be consistent with where I place the pointer/reference modifiers...

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;

    Node* createNode(const T &data)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = nullptr;

        return newNode;
    }

public:
    LinkedList();
    void display() const;
    void push(const T &data);
    void insert(const int pos, const T &data);
    void remove(const int pos);

};

template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() : head{ nullptr }, tail{ nullptr }, size{ 0 }
{
}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::display() const
{
    Node* curNode = head;

    while (curNode != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << curNode->data << std::endl;
        curNode = curNode->next;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::push(const T &data)
{
    Node* newNode = createNode(data);

    if (size == 0)
    {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }

    ++size;
}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(const int pos, const T &data)
{
    if (pos < 0 || pos > size)
    {
        std::cout << "Index is out of range!" << std::endl;   
    }
    else if (pos == size)
    {
        push(data);   
    }
    else
    {
        Node* newNode = createNode(data);
        Node* prevNode = head;
        Node* curNode = head;

        int i = 0;
        while (i != pos)
        {
            prevNode = curNode;
            curNode = curNode->next;
            ++i;
        }

        prevNode->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = curNode;

        ++size;
    }
}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::remove(const int pos)
{
    if (pos < 0 || pos > size)
    {
        std::cout << "Index is out of range!" << std::endl;   
    }
    else if (size == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "List is empty!" << std::endl;   
    }
    else
    {
        Node* prevNode = head;
        Node* curNode = head;

        int i = 1;
        while (i != pos)
        {
            prevNode = curNode;
            curNode = curNode->next;
            ++i;
        }

        prevNode->next = curNode->next;
        delete curNode;

        if (pos == size)
        {
            tail = prevNode;   
        }

        --size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your `LinkedList` does not manage its resources. You need a dtor, user-defined copy-ctor and user-defined assignment-operator at least.
2. Don't interact with the user from generic library code. Report any errors to the caller instead!
3. You probably want to provide the lists size to the public. Otherwise, consider whether optimizing removal of non-existent elements and insertion at the end by index is worth the overhead.
4. Only use `std::endl` if you really have to flush the stream. Remember flushing kills performance.
5. All your `while`-loops would be better off as `for`-loops.
6. `createNode` leaks memory if assignment to `.data` fails. Anyway, use aggregate-initialization, and you'll see that it's just not worth separating out into its own function:

   ```
   auto p = new Node{data};
   ```

Regarding defining things in-class: There's nothing wrong with that, it's often even preferable, especially for templates.
If you define something outside a class in a header though, remember it won't automatically marked `inline`, meaning it must not be included in more than one compilation-unit.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  I've incorporated the follow:
1. Still working on this one.
2. I now have my code utilizing `throw` to let the caller deal with the error.
3. I supplied a get function to get list size.
4. Replaced `std::endl` with `\n`
5. What's the thought behind this??
6. I believe the best way to address is this is via RAII - so I created a separate Node class that manages its own resources via constructors/destructors; if something fails when assigning to `.data`, the destructor should clean everything up.

Thanks again!

Comment: The thought behind number 5 is that if its written as a for-loop instead of just mimicking one using other constructs, it's easier to read, aside from being shorter. I personally am not in favor of using the node-class as anything but a plain old struct, everything more complicated done by the container. It's shorter, often more efficient and as nodes are just an implementation-detail anyway, there's no need for more abstraction or encapsulation.

Comment: I see - it looks like "aggregate initialization" and "uniform initialization" are the same thing?  How does aggregate/uniform initialization avoid the problem of creating a memory leak if assignment to `.data` fails?

Comment: Ok - I think using aggregate/uniform initialization prevents the leak because if there was some sort of problem with the initialization, an error would be thrown and nothing would be allocated in dynamic memory.  I think?

Comment: Aggregate initialization is one mode of uniform initialization. And it's just the way a new-expression works: Allocate memory, initialize object, if initialization fails, deallocate (always succeeds).

Answer (score 1):

Following up with the solution to separate the declaration/definition of the createNode function.  Because the createNode() function returns a type that's defined within a template class, and the Node return type depends on the template type "T", I need to use the keyword **typename** to declare that the return type is a dependent name.

Also, the return type Node* is not defined in the global scope, so I need to add the appropriate namespace as its prefix.

```
template<class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Node* LinkedList<T>::createNode(const T &data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: That's not exception-safe, you know?

Comment: I do not know; could you please expand on this?